# Maven not including dependencies

Tags: java, maven-3

I have this in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo.ch1</groupId>
  <artifactId>tutorials</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tutorials</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>image-processing</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.openimaj</groupId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>video-processing</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.openimaj</groupId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have been following this:

http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/processing-video.html

But for some reason the XuggleVideo classes and anything that has to do with video is not detected. 
My project is divided in separate packages. I don't think that matters in maven anyway.

Is my `pom.xml` file setup wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use this repo `<url>http://www.openimaj.org</url>` instead `<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>`

Comment: i tried it. same thing. Should I try restarting my IDE intellij?

Comment: what  do you mean "the XuggleVideo classes and anything that has to do with video is not detected". Is it error or do you not found this classes in repo?

Comment: The class is found in maven, but it comes as red when I use it.